# How to keep connector running when QuickBooks is close?

Tags: quickbooks

When I close my QuickBooks on my machine my Web Connector stops running:

> Application requested to abort

I want to keep my web connector running even when QuickBooks is close.
And also I choose the option while loading connector file: "Yes, always", which allows access even if QuickBooks is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a hook to listen for:

```
QUICKBOOKS_HANDLERS_HOOK_SENDREQUESTXML
```

The hook will pass you the company file path. [Reference](http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8047)